# "name of team members" or "names of team members"?

Tags: american-english, grammatical-number, british-english

Should I write "Please send me the name of team members" or "Please send me the names of team members"?

Comment: Try using 'of each'

Comment: A team is usually multiple people and you need all their **names**.

Comment: This isn't a case where the distributive singular ('All teenagers have a mobile phone nowadays' : ✓) sounds idiomatic. Use 'names'.